# input type number not cross browser friendly

Tags: html, input, cross-browser, numbers

I am working with a number input type eg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Quantity (between 1 and 5): <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This works nicely in chrome but not in firefox or IE. How can I make it work in IE9+, firefox etc? Or do I need alternative someone can suggest?

Comment: Nope: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you utilize javascript to provide field validation.  There are any number of libraries (or plug-ins to libraries) out there that perform form validation.

Comment: Any jquery plugin or similar I could use to achieve the up/down arrows?

Comment: I know jQuery UI "spinner" plug-in might provide the up/down arrow functionality. Obviously that is  pretty heavy library to take on just for this functionality, I am not sure how easy it would be to pare it down to only the parts you need.

Comment: This looks interesting as well... https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill  Google is your friend :)